# How do we predict if power loss will increase or decrease in a DC circuit?

Tags: dc, resistance, physics

I want to know whether it is possible to predict if power loss will increase or decrease in a circuit with a fixed EMF, a fixed resistor in series and a variable resistor in series.

If we change the variable resistor's resistance, how do we know if power loss over the variable resistor will increase or decrease? This is presuming we already know the values for EMF, the resistance of the fixed resistor and the original power loss before changing the resistance.

For example, if we double resistance, what happens to the power loss of the in the variable resistor?

Furthermore, we can assume no internal resistance.

I think its something related to the maximum power loss when load resistance equals internal resistance rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at this problem qualitatively, if the variable load resistance is either infinite or zero there is no power dissipation in the variable resistor load. So if we had an expression for the power dissipation in the variable load as a function of variable load resistance it would have a maxima at the series R0 resistance (we could guess, since that's like source resistance) and would decrease on either side.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgn5gA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We can derive this expression- current is V/(R0 +R), and power dissipation in the variable load R is \$I^2 R\$,  so load dissipation is \$V^2 R\over {(R0 + R)^2 }\$

Plot some typical values to get an idea: (V =5V, R0 = 5\$\Omega\$)

[image]

If you differentiate that expression wrt R to find the maxima you get
 \$-V^2 (R - R0)\over {(R + R0)^3}\$ , which is 0 at R = R0, as expected.

The curve is not monotonic- it decreases on either side of the series resistor value.

Comment: Oh i see . THANK YOU :D. ohhhhh. So pretty much, if the variable resistor's original resistance is less than the fixed resistor's resistance, and we increase the resistance of the variable resistor, We increase the power loss uptill the point where the 2 resistor's resistance is equal, which is the maximum power loss. From that point, if we increase the variable resistor's resistance, we achieve a power loss that decreases? Am i right? THANK you again

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a schematic for what you described. V1 and R1 is fixed, and R2 is variable.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkyCrV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Power through a resistor is 
$$ P = \frac {V^2}{R}  \space \space eq(1) $$

The voltage across R2 will be

$$ V_{R_2} = \frac {R_2}{R_1 + R_2}V_1 \space \space eq(2)$$

Substituting equation 2 into 1, we get

$$ P = \frac {(\frac {R_2}{R_1 + R_2}V_1)^2}{R_2} $$

Expanding this a little bit
$$ P = \frac {V_1^2R_2}{(R_1+R_2)^2} $$

If you look at the degree of R2 in in the numerator and denominator, you can see that the denominator has the larger degree. This means it changes much quicker than the numerator.

If you expanded it even more (you'll still see the same information, just more terms) you'll get the following
$$ P = \frac {V_1^2R_2}{R_2^2 + 2R_1R_2 + R_1^2} $$

Power loss decreases as R2 increases

Comment: It might be more clear if you left the denominator factored in the last equation. That way, it's more clear that as \$R_2\$ increases, the denominator will increase faster than the numerator (hence power loss gets smaller).

Comment: I tend to like to view things fully expanded but I added some of the middle bits.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, and everyone makes sense algebraiclly, but the markscheme says that as resistance is increased, the power loss increases. and also, ive tried substituting some different values of R2 in and ive realised some values increases the power when resistance increases?